# logstash ruby filter error with elasticsearch output

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a problem with ruby filter of logstash.

This is my ruby code in logstash.conf:

```
input {
  stdin {
    codec => json
  }
}
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
  ruby {
    code => "
      result = '';
      msg = event['payload']['check']['output'];
      result = msg.split(/\n/);
      event['check_output'] = result;
    "
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
     host => "host"
     port => "port"
  }
}
```

I got this error when run my config:

> Exception in filterworker {"exception"=>#register'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-ruby-0.1.5/lib/logstash/filters/ruby.rb:37:in`filter'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.0-java/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:162:in
>   `` multi_filter'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in`each'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.0-java/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:159:in
>   multi_filter'", "(eval):67:in`filter_func'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:219:in
>   filterworker'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.0-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:156:in ``
>   start_filters'"], :level=>:error}

But with the above code, i used the stdout{} output or file output, it's work fine as expected

So, I need some helps to find out this problem, I'm not sure it's about ruby issue or logstash issue. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Plz help me" won't help get help. Asking a well-written, well-researched, question will. I'd recommend reading "[ask]", especially the last link on the page, and "[mcve]".

Comment: Thank you, Tin Man. This my mistake, I post this question in a hurry context. But, this is a big problem with me, I run test for the above code many times, it's still stucked error. file or stdout output are ok.

The value of ['payload']['check']['output'] field:
CheckHTTP OK: 200, http://link1.com\nCheckHTTP CRITICAL: Request error: http://link2.com\nCheckHTTP OK: 200, http://link3.com\n

Comment: can try to use with hashes in ruby ? Because if you are using ruby filter in logstash, you should use it with hashes. Your configuration is correct, in my point of view, your problem is about ruby filter syntax

Comment: code => "
            hash = event.to_hash
            hash.each do |k,v|
                if v == nil
                    event.remove(k)
                end
            end
        "

Comment: Try to run this. if it runs its about syntax error